# I have a problema with right click in extension chrome manifest v3 to open my extension (No in tabs, no in popup)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm having a problem developing a Chrome extension, does anyone know if there's a possibility of opening my extension from Chrome's contextMenus?
Right mouse click to open dont work?

Example:
In background.js

```
    chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function () {
        chrome.contextMenus.create({
            title: "Test Ex",
            contexts: ["all"],
            id: "test"
        });
    });


    chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function (info, tab) {
        if (info.menuItemId === "test") {
            chrome.scripting.executeScript({
                target: { tabId: tab.id },
                function: () => {
                    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: "executeAuth" 
                }
             });
         }
    });
```

In content.js

```
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, sendResponse) {
        if (message.action === "executeAuth") {
            executeAuth();
        }
    });

    function executeAuth() {
        window.location.replace(`../Views/home.html`);
    }
```

But it doesn't work, is there any way I can do this?
I tried several solutions I found, but nothing managed to do what I want.

I need help with this problem, I've already tried several things, but the best thing would be to use the pop-up, but it's horrible (ugly).
If you can send an example if you have already done this, in manifest v-3.

Comment: Either replace `chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: "executeAuth" ` with `executeAuth()` or remove chrome.scripting.executeScript entirely and just use chrome.tabs.sendMessage with a tab id. You also need to [re-inject content scripts explicitly](/q/10994324) after reloading/installing the extension. BTW Your code is broken but I guess it's a copypaste mistake again.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix your issue as wOxxOm said. Here is my solution in the same way:

In **background.js**:

```
        chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function () {
        chrome.contextMenus.create({
            title: "Test Ex",
            contexts: ["all"],
            id: "test"
        });
    });

    chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function (info, tab) {
        if (info.menuItemId === "test") {
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, { action: "executeAuth" });
        }
    });
```

The content.js has no changes.

Read more at here: [Chrome extension message passing](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/messaging/)